# how to post the data into dotnet core api using .net core or simple c# console application

Tags: .net, console, .net-core

I want to create a dotnet core console application that read the text file and post the json data into dotnet core web api .
i didn't find much information about dotnet core console application.
can i get some sample code or link for reference?

Thank you so much

Comment: Creating a .NET Core Console application in just 5 minutes https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/luisdem/2016/06/01/creating-a-net-core-application-in-just-5-minutes/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the NuGet package RestSharp. It offers a nicely usable API for your needs.

- https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp/